# JAVA:How to output Array in 2 directions

Tags: java, arrays

My Title may sound a bit silly, so here is the explanation:

I have an Array

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

And the output in the End should be like

```
123321
```

I already managed to output 123456 and 654321 but I can´t figure out how to output 123321 :(
I am only allowed to use one outer loop and in this loop it is allowed to have a new loop.

I tried different things but I didn´t manage to get it running, can you guys give me a hint please? 
What I was thinking about in the beginning:

```
     while(x <=2){
            System.out.print(a[x]); 
            x++;
            if(x==2){
                while(x>0){
                    System.out.print(a[x]);
                    x--;
                }
            }
     }
```

Comment: Literal answer to your question ("I can´t figure out how to output 123321") is System.out.print("123321") ;-)

Comment: Are you just supposed to output the first three elements and then the same first three elements in reverse order?

Comment: using `break;` and `continue` will help you out. Hope that's a good hint.

Answer (score 4):

You should specify what conditions must the output meet.
For iterating to half of the array and then back to the beginning you don't need any inner loop. Try this:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i){
    if (i<a.length/2) System.out.print(a[i]);
    else System.out.print(a[a.length-i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you go to an infinite loop :

```
while(x <=2){
    System.out.print(a[x]); 
    x++;                        // <-- you increment x until it reaches 2
    if(x==2){                   // <-- x equals to 2
        while(x>0){
        System.out.print(a[x]);
        x--;                    // <-- you decrement x until it reaches 0
    }
}                               // <-- Wow, 0 <= 2 so re-execute the while loop
```

You can implement it like this. When you'll go until the middle of the array, the inner loop will get executed until it prints the elements from the current index to 0.

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int x = 0;
while(x != a.length/2){                 // <-- loop until the middle of the array
    System.out.print(a[x]);
    x++;
    if(x == a.length/2){                // <-- when we reach the middle execute the inner loop
        for(int i = x -1; i >= 0; i--)  // <-- print the elements of the array from current index to 0
            System.out.print(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You rock man! Thank you very much and have a nice evening :-)

Comment: @user2662907 generally you can accept this answer as proper one. can only +1

Answer (score 0):

Just other way with `Collections`:

```
    List<Integer> first = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ));
    int half = first.size()/2;      
    List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>( first.subList(0, half) );       
    Collections.reverse( first.subList( 0, half ) );        
    out.addAll( first.subList( 0, half ) );     
    System.out.println(out); // [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```